# Having <a> in <li> take up entire height in justified <ul>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GaJ2EOZe1SjJroQ4iGdv?p=preview) (make preview frame wider enough so each list item doesn't take up a whole line).

I have the following markup:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a href="">Here is the first link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Here is the second link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Yet another, this time with a lot more text that wraps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Here is the second link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like all anchors to take up the same height, 100% of the `li` they're contained in.  So if the anchor have enough text that it wraps within the list item, all the anchors should have that same height.

The issue appears to be how `.nav-justified` is implemented in that the list items have `display: table-cell;` which is required to allow them to be justified, but prevents the anchors from taking up the entire height.  Any way around this other than making the list items have a static height?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D: What more do you need?  I've included the markup.  There are no styles outside of Bootstrap styles.

Comment: Ok...but you can't make elements 100% of table-cells (which is what is happening) without a specified height.

Comment: @Paulie_D: So I guess the question restated is "How can you make the height of anchors in a justified list be 100% of their parents?"

Comment: I would use flexbox but I guess but this might break bootstraps default styling (which is CSS Tables).

Answer (score 1):

Giving a height in pixel to li do the trick.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/o35meq9p/)

```
li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:80px; 
}
```

Comment: Setting a static height on the `li` is a last resort.